# nargout in Python

Tags: python, multiple-variable-return

Does Python have any equivalent of nargout in MATLAB? I find nargout a very neat approach if we want to keep the number of return parameters flexible. Is there a way I can find out how many output parameters have been requested? Something like the following pseudo-python-code:

```
def var_returns_func(a):
  """
  a is a 1D numpy array
  """
  if nargout==1: return a.sum()
  elif nargout==2: return a.sum(),a.std()
```

So if I call this function as `mean = var_returns_func(someNumPyarray)`, it should return a single value. But if I call it as `mean,std = var_returns_func(someNumPyarray)`, it should return 2 values.

Is there a Pythonic way of doing this? Or a hacky way?

Answer (score 19):

The function can't know what is going to be done with the return value, so it can't know how many are needed.  What you could do is pass `nargout` as an argument to your function and use that to decide what to return:

```
def f(a, nargout=1):
    if nargout == 1:
        return "one value"
    elif nargout == 2:
        return "two", "values"
    else:
        raise ValueError, "Invalid nargout!"
```

This is an example of "explicit is better than implicit" as a Python philosophy.  If you want two arguments out, you have to say explicitly that you want two arguments out.  Implicitly deciding based on looking into the future to see what is going to be done with the result is discouraged in Python.  It's perfectly possible to do `a = f(x)` and *want* to get a two-element tuple in a.

For examples like yours, there are lots of better ways.  One is to just do `mean, std = a.mean(), a.std()`, or more generally `x, y = someFunc(a), otherFunc(a)`.  If this particular combination of values is commonly needed, and there is some expensive computation shared by both operations that you don't want to duplicate, make a third function that clearly returns both and do `x, y = funcThatReturnsTwoThings(a)`.  All of these are explicit ways of keeping functions separate if they do different things.

Comment: Thanks! Though this is what I had been doing so far to handle such a situation. Ideally, there should be no need to pass a separate input argument to specify the number of output arguments.  It is a little disappointing that Python does not support this feature. This has been around in MATLAB for ages, I believe. The function definition in MATLAB allows specification of multiple output arguments.

Comment: @Nik: "Explicit is better than implicit".  Python doesn't like this kind of magic.  (I added a bit of explanation to my answer.)

Comment: I agree with the explicit vs implicit argument. If this is Pythonic philosophy, then I rest my case.

Comment: Matlabs nargout is not magic, nor is it implicit, nor is Matlabs `[a, b] = f(x)` analogous to Pythons `(a, b) = f(x)`.  Rather, the syntax `[a, b] = f(x)` in Matlab results in Matlab telling `f` that `nargout=2`.  It's a well-defined syntactical rule in the Matlab language, with no ambiguous cases.  This Matlab feature is unusual and does not occur in Python or any other language I know.  However, I don't think this is because of any rule in the Zen of Python.

Comment: Another example of pythons redundant syntax: as previously mentioned, the Matlab syntax allows the interpreter to know how many arguments are requested when the function is called and then nargout is defined without having to pass it explicitly as well as defining multiple output arguments to store them.

Answer (score 12):

I cannot speak for `nargout` in MATLAB as I do not know it and I cannot imagine how it should be used correctly. However, you may want to change you view to what a Python function (or method) really does).

Actually, Python always returns exactly one value. Or it is None, or it is a single value of some specific type, or it is a single object of the `tuple` type.

If there is no `return` command, the function returns `None` if the function body ends. It is the same as if you explicitly wrote `return` without arguments at the end of body, or `return None` at the end of body.

If you use `return None` (the `None` can be stored in a variable) or `return` without arguments, the `None` is returne to the caller.

If you `return single`, the `single` object is return to the caller.

If you `return v1, v2, v3`, you actually return a tuple `(v1, v2, v3)`. It is just a syntactic sugar that you need not to write the parentheses.

The `result1, result2, result3 = f()` in the case is just another syntactic sugar. The `f()` returns the tuple and its elements are automatically extracted to the given variables. You actually do:

```
result1, result2, result3 = (v1, v2, v3)
```

or

```
t = f()                           # where t is the (v1, v2, v3)
result1, result2, result3 = t
```

Actually, Python does not allow to define output arguments as it is usual in other languages. You can think in terms you are passing addresses of the argument objects and if the passed object allows to be modified, you can modify it. But you can never get a new result to a passed argument that had initially `None` value, for example. You cannot assign a Python variable via output argument of the function -- no mechanism like that in Python.

The only natural and direct way to return newly created values (objects) from inside the function is to use the `return` command. However, a Python function does not limits you how many arguments can be returned. (Well, always a single one that can be later broken to elements if it was a tuple.)

If you want to test in the caller code what was actually returned, you can write your own function that does something special in cases where the following values were returned: `None`, `single`, a tuple of some length (`len(t)` can be used to get the number of elements in the returned tuple `t`). Your function can also test the type of `single` or of the each of the tuple elements and work accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I know about Python's return types and that one may return multiple items as a tuple. My question was about output _arguments_.

Comment: This is in the third from the bottom paragraph. Python does not have output arguments. You can only pass a modifiable or non-modifiable object via the argument. But each call of the function can pass whatever (different) object. The arguments cannot be marked in source code as being modifiable or *output*. You have to change the way of thinking about the solution. It would be nice to see a concrete example that you want to solve.

Answer (score 5):

What I tend to do is make my function return everything (as elements of a tuple), then only unpack the ones I need:

```
def my_func():
    # do stuff...
    return mean, stddev, otherstat, a, b

mu, sig, _, a, _ = myfunc()
```

Here Im returning everything, but only assigning the 1st 2nd and 4th variables to variables I will use in the calling scope. The `_` variable is a throwaway to act as a placeholder for the variables I dont want/need.

Comment: In case more people stumble upon this: you can also take the values that you need and unpack the rest in a **throaway tuple**, for instance `mu, *_ = myfunc()`. The main interest is that you do not need to know how many useless returned values are discarded.

Answer (score 5):

I have a strange idea ...

```
def nargout():
   import traceback
   callInfo = traceback.extract_stack()
   callLine = str(callInfo[-3].line)
   split_equal = callLine.split('=')
   split_comma = split_equal[0].split(',')
   return len(split_comma)

def fun():
   this = nargout()
   if this == 1:
       return 3
   else:
       return 3, 4

a = fun()
a, b = fun()
```

I really miss Matlab now :D

---

Improved by:

```
def nargout(*args):
   import traceback
   callInfo = traceback.extract_stack()
   callLine = str(callInfo[-3].line)
   split_equal = callLine.split('=')
   split_comma = split_equal[0].split(',')
   num = len(split_comma)
   return args[0:num] if num > 1 else args[0]

def fun(nparray):
   return nargout(np.mean(nparray), np.std(nparray))

arr = np.array([3, 4, 5])
mean = fun(arr)
mean, std = fun(arr)
```

Comment: I have to say that this is not perfect. It find the line of command which called your function, and determine how many argument should be returned by counting the amount of ',' before '=', so when your command is written in multiple rows, this will not work ...

Comment: nice idea though

Comment: I really like this idea. Using Python 3.9 on Linux it worked out of the box. Using Python 3.8 on Windows though, the split command returned a list of one element even though the split character was not present - also I needed to use the `traceback.format_list` to get the command. It should be possible to extend this idea for multi-line command.

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab, the number of output arguments is actually one of the inputs to a function. This is not the case in Python and so you have set up the function's interface to reflect this differently.

For example, here's a function that applies upper() to a group of strings, and the user can expect the the number of inputs equals the number of outputs. The syntax is also very similar to Matlab's.

```
>>> def var_returns_f(*args):
...     return [str.upper() for str in args]
... 
>>> 
>>> a, b = var_returns_f('one', 'two')
>>> 
>>> a
'ONE'
>>> b
'TWO'
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @yiping jiao's idea, I made a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
from traceback import extract_stack

def with_nargout(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _with_nargout(*args, **kwargs):
        global nargout
        call_line = extract_stack()[-2].line
        if '=' in call_line:
            nargout = len(call_line.split('=')[0].split(','))
        else:
            nargout = 0
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        del nargout
        return result
    return _with_nargout
```

an example:

```
@with_nargout
def func_1(x, y):
    print('nargout is', nargout)
    if nargout == 1:
        return x + y
    elif nargout == 2:
        return x + y, nargout
    print('returning None')

a = func_1(14, 53)
a, b = func_1(15, 43)
print(func_1(14, 39))
```